# Windows Mail Server with an api

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, email-server

I am looking for an mail server for windows with an api, the reason for this is that i want to let my uses be able to add new accounts and such forth to the mail server, but i have not really been ably to find one.
Do any of you know a windows mail server that has an api, so external programs can control it.

Comment: Are you familiar with PowerShell scripting? Exchange exports objects for managing mailboxes with powershell.

Comment: do you want these people to be able to delete accounts also?

Answer (score 1):

Exchange has a complete management API see [Exchange Server 2010 SP1 Management Shell SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff326155)